# Linux and Apache curl issues

Tags: linux, apache, curl

I am having some issues getting my curl to work. So Here are the modifications I made to my `httpd.conf` file see below. (`apache 2.4`, `Centos 7`)

So I am not sure what the issue is? I keep trying to use the:

```
curl http://localhost/server-status
```

but I get:

```
error: You don't have permission to access /server-status
on this server.

[root@localhost conf]# curl http://localhost/server-status


 56 Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
 57 LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
 58
 59 ExtendedStatus on
 60
 61 <Location /server-status>
 62   SetHandler server-status
 63   Require local
 64 </Location>


107 ServerName localhost
108
109 <Directory /var/www/path/to/your/web/documents>
110    order allow,deny
111    deny from 192.168.XXX.XXX
112    allow from all
113 </Directory>
114
115 # Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
116 # explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
117 # <Directory> blocks below.
118 #
119 <Directory />
120     AllowOverride none
121     Require all denied
122 </Directory>
123


136 DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
137
138 <Directory "/">
139     AllowOverride None
140     Require all denied
141 </Directory>
142
143 <Location "/server-status">
144     SetHandler server-status
145     Order deny,allow
146     Deny from all
147     Allow From 127.0.0.1
148 </Location>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Are you trying to access this from localhost? If not, then `Require local` may be the problem (I guess that's what it means).